# HttpServletRequest Get request header parameter block

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

Query the log and find that getting the request header parameter will be blocked
The code is as follows:

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object 
handler){
    logger.debug(".........................preHandle start .........................");
    logger.info("================== REQUEST IP:{} ==================",this.getIpAdrress(request));
    String languageCode = request.getHeader("language");
    LOGGER.info("================== request header languageCode:{} ================== ",languageCode);
    LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(new Locale(LanguageEnum.getName(languageCode)));
    return true;
}
```

log image

[image]

I have done some related tests and determined that HttpServletRequest getheader blocking leads to too long time, but I can't find a solution.

The JDK version we use is 1.8 and spring boot 2.3.4

We have also tried some solutions of securerandom, but none of them can solve the problems we encounter

Comment: what is the difference between logger and LOGGER in your code?

Comment: What about other requests: is there always a delay here? I don't think get header is the problem

Comment: logger and LOGGER No difference
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

Comment: This is the public interceptor，Irregular delay，Locating according to the log is the problem of obtaining the header